# Inherited Generics Constructor C#

Tags: c#, generics, constructor, multiple-inheritance

Hi I'm trying to make a generic treenode.  Here is the abstract generic class

```
public abstract class TreeNode<T>
{
    protected List<TreeNode<T>> _childNodes = new List<TreeNode<T>>();
    protected TreeNode<T> ParentNode;

    public T ObjectData { get; set; }

    public TreeNode( TreeNode<T> parent, T data)
    {
        ParentNode = parent;
        ObjectData = data;
    }    
}
```

It has a companion interface

```
interface TreeNodeOperations<T>
{
    //Adds child to tree node
    public abstract void AddChild<T>(T child);
    //Performs N-Tree search
    public abstract TreeNode<T> SeachChild<T>(T child);
}
```

What I'm trying to do is inherit from both of these:

```
public class FHXTreeNode<T>: TreeNode<T>, TreeNodeOperations<T> where T : ParserObject
{
    public FHXTreeNode(FHXTreeNode<T> parent, T data) ---> # **ERROR** #
    {
        ParentNode = parent;
        ObjectData = data;
    }

    //Adds child to tree node
    public override FHXTreeNode<T> AddChild<ParserObject>(T childData)
    {
        FHXTreeNode<T> child = new FHXTreeNode<T>(this, childData);

        //_childNodes.Add(child);        

        return child;
    }

}
```

The error is: ***'Parser.Objects.TreeNode' does not contain a constructor that takes 0 arguments***

Help Pls!

Answer (score 10):

You need to add a call to the base class' constructor.

And, subsequently, you don't need to set the properties inside of FHXTreeNode's constructor since it's handled in the base class' constructor. Your new constructor should look like this:

```
public FHXTreeNode(FHXTreeNode<T> parent, T data) : base(parent, data)
{
}
```

Comment: Thanks alot.  This is a big help!

Answer (score 6):

You need to call the constructor of the base class. If you omit the `:base(...)` call, the parameterless constructor of the base class gets called. Since your base class doesn't have such a constructor, you get an error.

```
public FHXTreeNode(FHXTreeNode<T> parent, T data)
   :base(parent, data)
{
}
```

Calling the parameterized base class constructor makes the field initializations obsolete too, since they already get assigned to in the base class.

In C# you can't inherit constructors. You create a new constructor in the derived class that happens to have the same signature as the base class constructor.

---

Your interface is broken too: You can't declare methods as `public abstract` in an interface. Interface methods are always implicitly public, and never have an implementation. So those modifiers would be redundant, and are illegal.

---

Next you can't `override` interface methods. You can only override `virtual`/`abstract` methods from a *base class*. When you have a method which matches a method in an interface, in implements that interface method.

---

Yet another mistake is that you reuse the type parameter on the interface methods: `void AddChild<T>(T child);` is wrong. This syntax is for introducing type parameters on a method. But you want to use the type parameter from the containing type. So you should write `AddChild(T child);`.

---

There are also a few stylistic issues: Interface names should be prefixed with `I`. And I'd avoid `protected` fields where possible.

Comment: Thanks for your input, actually what I wanted to do was introduce type parameters in the method, so what I should take out is the <T> in the interface name.  I really appreciate your suggestions.

Comment: Are you sure you wanted to introduce type parameters in the method and not in the interface type? Making these methods generic makes little sense.

Comment: Yes coz these interfaces were made because I realized that for example, not all trees add children in the same way.  If I were to put it in the abstract base class, I would have to overload the addChild method, and the resulting code would be worse than what it is now.  Since not all trees add and search children in the same way, i was thinking of adapting a Strategy pattern to implement these tree operations.

Answer (score 3):

You have to call the base class constructor from your FHXTreeNode constructor:

```
public FHXTreeNode(FHXTreeNode<T> parent, T data)
    : base(parent, data)
{
    ParentNode = parent;
    ObjectData = data;
}
```

Also, by convention, interfaces start with an uppercase I in .NET, so TreeNodeOperations should be ITreeNodeOperations

Answer (score 3):

First of all, `public` and `abstract` are not valid keywords in interface declarations. Your interface should look like this:

```
interface TreeNodeOperations<T>
{
    //Adds child to tree node
    void AddChild(T child);
    //Performs N-Tree search
    TreeNode<T> SeachChild(T child);
}
```

To answer your question, since `TreeNode` does not define a parameterless constructor like so:

```
public TreeNode() { }
```

...then an instance of FHXTreeNode cannot be created without calling its base constructor like so:

```
public FHXTreeNode(FHXTreeNode<T> parent, T data) : base(parent, data) { }
```